# Looking to buy a sound effects pack (hand-to-hand combat impact sounds)

Tags: effects

Hi all,

Im doing the sound design for a short film that primarily involves fighting. I'm looking to buy a sound effects pack like this, http://arrowheadaudiosfx.com/AAS-004.html. Except that im looking for more of a compilation of 'fighting impact' sounds, like a punch or kick to the gut kinda thing. So im looking for more of a pack/compilation rather than those single sounds. Does anyone have a recommendation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://hissandaroar.com/sd001-vegetable-violence/

http://hissandaroar.com/sd002-swishes/

created by Tim Prebble

Comment: feel fry to try & free versions too, if in any doubt ;)

http://hissandaroar.com/free-sounds/

Comment: I listened to the sample and felt that it wasnt really suitable. But then i went back and gave it another listen and the sounds of the rod smacking the cabbage actually could work! Thanks for the renewed sense of hope!

Comment: if you are a sound editor it is not about one sound, later a few elements for the hit, and a few slightly later for decay and a swish before the hit for the arm movement... careful syncing & layering is what makes a sound fit picture & be interesting/characterful

Comment: layer not later

Answer (score 3):

Even if you get a really awesome sound effects pack, I wouldn't recommend using them as they come. You should try layering different and apparently unrelated sounds to get just the right sound effects. That said, it doesn't make a great difference what you use as starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using these for a while now, and very satisfied about it: http://www.boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=77
http://www.boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78

Answer (score 0):

I've had my eye on this one for some time now:
http://www.tonsturm.com/Soundpacks/files/d954f4e449850afd3e294da133cb3b41-14.html